# How can I round and print a floating point number in a minimum width format in Perl

Tags: perl, string-formatting

I wanted to do something like:

```
printf('%3.3f%% ', $percent);
```

But I'm still getting the output as:

```
99.999%
100.000%
```

I would like something like:

```
 99.999%
100.000%
```

So it pads less than the full width with spaces. What format specifier would accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number *before* the dot represents the minimum value for the *full field width*, so you need 7 in there to allow for three digits before and after the decimal point, and one more for the point itself:

```
printf "%7.3f%%\n", $_ for 99.999, 100;
```

**output**

```
 99.999%
100.000%
```